# Play multiple videos

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm actually using the `MPMoviePlayerController` for play video in my iPad app.

Actually, I can easly play 1 video but I'm trying to play in the same time 2 video, here is my code :

```
// Look for the video in the main bundle
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];

NSString *urlStr2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr2];

videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 200); 

videoPlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url2];
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer2.view];
videoPlayer2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300,200, 200);

[videoPlayer2 play];
NSLog(@"Video 1 playing");

[videoPlayer play];
NSLog(@"Video 2 playing");
```

The first video is correctly launched but not the second. (and btw the second video does not lauch after the first finished)

Here is my output :

```
2012-06-18 13:47:23.015 testMosaique[2498:11f03] Video 1 playing

2012-06-18 13:47:23.016 testMosaique[2498:11f03] Video 2 playing
```

Is there a way while using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play 2 or more videos at the same time?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is display 4 videos using AVPlayer, but those video are made from 4 another video (I create each videos with AVFoundation). Si I'm able the display thousand and thousand videos in only 4 players, pretty good performances when you play the videos !

Comment: My code is a little bit dirty, but here you have the tutorial that I have used for achieve this : http://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play more than one video at the same time you have to use `AVPlayer` frameworks. `MPMovie` only allowed you play one video at a time.

See `AVPlayer` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Safecase mentioned, **MPMovieplayerController** will only allow one video to be played at a time. But here is an example to play two simultaneously with the use of **AVFoundation**:

http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I actually use. Btw AVFoundation allow you to display only 4 or less video right?

Comment: @Edelweiss I don't know if it has a limit in itself, but you could more easily run into memory/performance problems, the more videos you display at the same time.

Comment: What I did is display 4 videos using AVPlayer, but those video are made from 4 another video (I create each videos with AVFoundation). Si I'm able the display thousand and thousand videos in only 4 players, pretty good performances when you play the videos !