# How I will show multiple video's , images? When I am uploading multiple images and vieos

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to use UICollectionView to show multiple images like my Screenshot.Can anyone suggest me how I will manage this design.

Like This

[image: Collection View Example Image]

Comment: Kindly attach screenshot with the question.

Comment: @BhavikModi Attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SizeForItemAt function to set custom sizes for each cell and add a button inside the last cell to open the last two images or use didSelectItemAt to open the last cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
      var collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size
   if indexPath.row == 0 {
      collectionViewSize.width = collectionViewSize.width/2.0 //Display 2 items in a row.
      collectionViewSize.height = collectionViewSize.height/2.0
     }
 if indexPath.row == 1 {

  collectionViewSize.width = collectionViewSize.width/3.0 //Display 3 items in row
  collectionViewSize.height = collectionViewSize.height/2.0
  }
      return collectionViewSize
}





 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return yourImageArray.count
}



   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt    indexPath:  IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell 
cell.imageView.image = yourImageArray[indexPath.item] as UIImage
return cell 
}
```

*remember to set UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your ViewController

Answer (score 0):

If want to play more than one video in same view, you can use AVPlayer of AVFoundation.I have read more about this in StackOverflow and AppleDoucument and Other forums.All they say is not possible using MPMoviePlayerViewController.But it is possible using AVPlayer.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import CoreMedia

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var optionalInteger: Int?
var Asset1: AVAsset?
var Asset2: AVAsset?
var Asset3: AVAsset?
var audioAsset: AVAsset?
var loadingAssetOne = false


@IBOutlet weak var musicImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var videoViewTwo: UIView!

var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    musicImg.hidden = true
    let gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture")

    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    imageViewVideoOne.hidden = true
    imageViewVideoTwo.hidden = true
}
func startMediaBrowserFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController!, usingDelegate delegate : protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>!) -> Bool 
{

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
        return false
    }

    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum



    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate
    presentViewController(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true

}
 // click first video
@IBAction func FirstVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        loadingAssetOne = true
         optionalInteger = 0
        startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

}

// clcik second video
@IBAction func SecondVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

        loadingAssetOne = false
        optionalInteger = 1
        startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

}
// click audio
@IBAction func Audio(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Any)
    mediaPickerController.delegate = self
    mediaPickerController.prompt = "Select Audio"
    presentViewController(mediaPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
 @IBAction func playPreview(sender: AnyObject) 
 {
    startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)
 }
 extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 
 {

    // display the first & second video after it picked from gallery
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) 
    {
      let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
      dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

      if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie 
      {
        if loadingAssetOne 
        {
          let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)
          print(avAsset)
            if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                self.videoURL = vURL

            } else {
                print("oops, no url")
            }
            mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  let videoURLWithPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
            self.videoURL = videoURLWithPath!
            asset = AVAsset(URL: videoURL) as AVAsset

            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
            player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            videoView.frame = CGRectMake(38, 57, 220, 106)
            playerLayer?.frame = videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

            player!.play()
        } 
        else 
        {
           let avAssetTwo = AVAsset(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)
            print(avAssetTwo)
           if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                self.videoURL = vURL
            } else {
                print("oops, no url")
            }
            mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
          let videoURLWithPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
           self.videoURL = videoURLWithPath!
           asset = AVAsset(URL: videoURL) as AVAsset

            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
            player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            videoView.frame =  CGRectMake(38, 206, 220, 106)
            playerLayer?.frame =  videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
            player!.play()
           }
         }
       }
 }
```

Sources for your question

[Multiple Video same screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828256/multiple-video-same-screen)

[Multiple Video Playback on iOS](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/)

[Apple MPMoviePlayerViewController Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

[Playing Multiple Video Simultaneously](http://www.sdkboy.com/2011/07/video-on-the-iphone-tutorial-part-3-playing-multiple-videos-simultaneously/)

[Apple AVPlayer Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html)

[Playing Multiple Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082206/play-multiple-videos)

[Playback](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)

[Playing Video in iOS](http://jacopretorius.net/2013/02/playing-video-in-ios.html)

Comment: I am not asking about. How to upload multiple image ? Read Carefully then answer.

Comment: Edited my answer. please check